# ie 9 browser compatibility

Tags: cross-browser, internet-explorer-9

I installed ie 9 and tried to bring up my application. I could see that the css is applied properly and the page renders well. When a colleague of mine did the samething he didnt get the page correctly. All the paragraphs were looking disaligned and extra spaces and lot more issues.

On checking the browser mode and document mode of my machine by pressing F12 it was IE9 compatibility view and IE7 standards respectively. For my colleague it was IE9 for both the modes.

Questions:
1) Why is the setting different in each installation of IE9 in different machines ? 
2) How to control the setting to make it uniform in all the machines ?

Comment: What doctype does your page have? IE's Document mode depends on the doctype primarily.

Comment: Here is a list of factors that IE uses to determine the Document mode for a web page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff405803%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Have you checked Compatibility View settings (in Tools menu)? By default, IE often has the option "Display intranet sites in Compat. view" enabled, and localhost is considered belonging to intranet. Anyways, you can override the Compatibility View settings with the `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />` tag (it must come in the `<head>` before the `<title>`).

Comment: Thanks Ilya. The meta tag option worked.

Answer (score 0):

1) IE settings are depend on your installation and older version of IE. It's always different in each machine.

2) Just put following code in your header and your IE browser would open by default in defined compatible view.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9">
```

You can change "IE=EmulateIE9" to "IE=EmulateIE9" if you want make IE8 as default compatibility view.